# How to determine a spherical triangle exist when given the length of three sides

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, trigonometry

Denote the spherical distance $d(A,B)$ of two points $A,B$ on some unit sphere surface is the shortest distance of path from A to B on the surface.

Given length of three sides $a,b,c$. Ask what's the sufficient and necessary condition for $a,b,c$ such that there exists three point $A,B,C$ on the unit sphere surface and $d(A,B)=a,d(B,C)=b,d(C,A)=c$.

Comment: Is that anything like a spherical cow?

Comment: @JasonB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines

Comment: What exactly *is* a spherical triangle, by your definition? What Euler work are you referring to? Personally I'd have applied the term to any configuration of three geodetic segments which connect to one another through common endpoints in a cyclical fashion. This does allow for $a+b=c$, or for $c>\pi$, so apparently you have a different definition.

Comment: @MvG, thanks for your question. I have edited to give a formal definition of spherical triangle. Now it is degenerate in the sense that a+b could equal to c. But still $0<=a,b,c<=\pi$, because I define the distance of two points as the shortest distance in the sphere.

Comment: @MvG, the Euler's work is here : http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXI/propXI20.html, http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXI/propXI21.html